# Get option set and lookup field values from FetchXml in CRM 2011

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, fetchxml

I'm attempting to use fetchxml to obtain values from another record to create a new one. I have managed to get it all working apart from getting any values from option set or lookup fields. The option set ones dont give any error but just dont set the field at all and the lookups say that the GUID is not in the correct format, presumably because it is not passing through a GUID.

Can anyone help me figure out how to get these values?

Thanks

EDIT: My code is below. The option set is grading (ts_grading) and its the qualityStatement Guid (ts_quality_statement_id) i need to get from the fetch.

```cs
string fetchXml = @"<fetch distinct='false' mapping='logical' output-format='xml-platform' version='1.0'>
                            <entity name='ts_self_assessment_item'>
                            <attribute name='ts_evidence_of_areas_of_improvement'/><attribute name='ts_evidence_of_strengths'/><attribute name='ts_expected_completion_date'/>
                            <attribute name='ts_grading'/><attribute name='ts_quality_statement_id'/>
                            <filter type='and'>
                            <condition attribute='ts_self_assessment_id' uitype='ts_self_assessment' operator='eq' value='" + selfAssessmentID + "'/></filter></entity></fetch>";

        // Execute Fetch xml
        EntityCollection selfAssessmentItemResult = Service.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));

        foreach (var selfAssessment in selfAssessmentItemResult.Entities)
        {                
            string areasOfImprovement = selfAssessment["ts_evidence_of_areas_of_improvement"].ToString();
            string strengths = selfAssessment["ts_evidence_of_strengths"].ToString();
            DateTime completionDate = Convert.ToDateTime(selfAssessment["ts_expected_completion_date"].ToString());
            string grading = selfAssessment["ts_grading"].ToString();
            Guid qualityStatement = new Guid(selfAssessment["ts_quality_statement_id"].ToString());
            Guid parentSelfAssessment = new Guid(entity.Attributes["ts_self_assessmentid"].ToString());              

        }

    }
```

Comment: Could you post some of the code that's not working for you?

Comment: Optionset values are numeric and not guids - agree with @PeterMajeed, code would help!

Comment: I have posted the code in my original post

Answer (score 7, accepted):

OptionSet Attributes are returned as OptionSetValues and foriegn keys are returned as Entity References.  Try using the Entity.GetAttributeValue instead of doing all of that ToString casting work:

```cs
    foreach (var selfAssessment in selfAssessmentItemResult.Entities)
    {                
        string areasOfImprovement = selfAssessment.GetAttributeValue<String>("ts_evidence_of_areas_of_improvement");
        string strengths = selfAssessment.GetAttributeValue<string>("ts_evidence_of_strengths");
        DateTime completionDate = selfAssessment.GetAttributeValue<DateTime>("ts_expected_completion_date");
        var grading = selfAssessment.GetAttributeValue<OptionSetValue>("ts_grading");
        Guid qualityStatement = selfAssessment.GetAttributeValue<EntityReference>("ts_quality_statement_id").Id;

    }
```

And if you want the OptionSetValue Text value, you'll need to look it up using the OptionSet metadata service call or looking in the Entity.FormattedAttributes property.

Also using early bound objects will keep you from having these types of casting issues.

Comment: Great, that worked thanks. As a side question how do you use early bound objects with CRM?

Comment: @jimminybob you have to create them with a tool in the SDK.  Basically you just point the tool to your CRM endpoints, and it will generate objects for you so you can get all of your intellisense, and it allows you to use LINQ even rather than Fetch XML. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg327844.aspx

Comment: I would now (well, I guess since 2013) suggest using the Early Bound Generator from the XrmToolBox to generate your early bound entities.  It uses the same SDK tool as I mention above, but is a wrapper around the command line, so it is easier to setup, and has a lot more options about generation.